# MySQL VARCHAR size? 25MB

Tags: php, mysql, file-storage

I have a HTML form with a file/image upload field, which is processed by a PHP script. I want to prevent users from uploading files larger than 25MB. How can I do this?

Secondly, I want to store this file in a MySQL table. What data-type should I use?

Comment: how exactly are you planing to store an file/image in MySql column ?

Comment: $file_path = $mysqli->real_escape_string('file/' . $_FILES['file']['name']);

Answer (score 2):

File-size verification should be done by the PHP code that receives the file, before sending it to MySQL. Something like this should work:

```
if ($_FILES['file']['size'] > 25*1024*1024) {
    throw new RuntimeException('Exceeded filesize limit.');
}
```

Have a look at the [PHP doc page](http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.php) about file uploads.

Also, if you want to store the actual file in a MySQL table, have a look at the [BLOB data-types](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/blob.html).